# iOS: get an instance variable value (property) from delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, properties

I'm developing a simple app with multiple views.
I have a base view and a second view, called after the base. 
The base view serves as a delegate for the second view.

I would like, in my second view, to set and retrieve the value of a property in the baseView (the 'name').
Since, in the secondView, the delegate is a secondViewDelegate object, it doesn't have a 'name' method.

baseView.h (skipping imports):

```
@interface baseView : UIViewController <secondViewDelegate> {
}
@property (retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

secondView.h (skipping imports):

```
@protocol secondViewDelegate;

@interface secondView : UIViewController{
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <secondViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol secondViewDelegate 
- (void) secondViewDidFinish:(secondView *)controller;
@end
```

What is the usual approach here?
Do I really need to implement a getter and a setter for the protocol? Like:

```
@protocol secondViewDelegate 
- (void) secondViewDidFinish:(secondView *)controller;
- (NSString *)getName;
- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName;
@end
```

Or is there any good way to actually access the baseView property, or at least get the  instance? (Is it a good idea?)

I'm still pretty new to iOS development, in case it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you go to the trouble of defining a delegate protocol (a good thing IMO), you should stick to your design decision and add the property to the protocol instead of looking for a "clever" solution that makes the warning go away. You can use `@property` for the protocol declaration, like this:

```
@protocol secondViewDelegate
@property(retain) NSString* name;
@end
```

If it doesn' feel good to have the property in your protocol, then you should probably review your design decisions: What is `secondViewDelegate` supposed to do, or why does `secondView` need to set the property.

Comment: Yep, that's it! While we're at it, could I do this without a delegate protocol? Can the secondview call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, instead of this being called in the baseView?

Comment: @jpimentel: I don't think that this is possible, the view controller who does the presenting also must do the dismissing. But that's a good thing, since it keeps responsibility together in one class. But you could redesign your protocol so that it consists of a single method with the signature `secondView:(secondView*)controller didFinishWithName:(NSString*)name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call its -name or -setName: methods, although resulting in a compiler warning, they'll work.
Edit: if you cast the object to the appropriate type, it won't even warn.

Comment: Yeah, it sure does. But compiler warnings usually tell me "you're not supposed to be doing that".

Comment: Usually, but not every time. It's the dynamic nature of Obj-C that is the problem here. The compiler has hints only about which methods does a particular class/object respond to. That's why it's a warning, not an error. Have you ever built cool, well-coded Unix stuff from source with CFLAGS=-Wall? You saw the tons of warnings?

Comment: @H2CO3: So you would recommend to go through an interface (or protocol, since we are talking Obj-C) to access a property that is **not** part of the interface, just because the language lets you get away with it at runtime?

Comment: Of course I don't feel bad about the classic -Wall warning "No new line at end of file" :)